# Trying to host local website

Tags: github, github-pages

I am trying to host my local website on github pages I currently have the upload folder next to the readme and the index.html that says Hello World. This is currently what I have.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfrQ6.jpg

How can I move all the stuff in the folder to the same level as that index.html? Literally my whole website is in that folder with all the pictures, css, and js. I am new to github so baby steps are needed. Thanks for the help!

EDIT: I have cloned the branch, but now when I try to move it I get an error.

fatal: destination exists, source=upload/index.html, destination=index.html

nvm debugged it had to remove index.html first

Answer (score 2):

You can clone that GitHub repository, and (once cloned locally), do a:

```
cd /path/to/my/clone
git rm index.html
git mv upload/* .
git commit -m "move upload content"
git push
```

Comment: so that /* is the repository?

Comment: No: `upload/*` represents all the files and folders directly under `upload`. They are git moved to the current top folder

Comment: Thanks haha rookie mistake I have seen that syntax before just has been awhile

Comment: So i cannot do the git mv upload/* . command in my ubuntu terminal. I get a fatal: destination exists... I cloned the gh-pages branch @vonc                                    fatal: destination exists, source=upload/index.html, destination=index.html

Comment: @train55255 if your `upload/index.html` is the right one, then do first a `git rm index.html`

Comment: @train55255 I have added that missing step to the answer for more visibility.